# Postfix + Dovecot User Auth

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am following the link below

https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/

Setup a email server on one of my debian box.

1. I am able to send email through swaks, from my windows pc 
   through `swaks -t admin@jmail -s 192.168.56.101:25 -d b1.eml`
   (but when I use admin/password I get Host did not advertise authentication)
2. from 192.168.56.101's SquirrelMail, I can send to my gmail

My problem are

1. I have to use my debian username to logi the SquirrelMail
   but why I don't need a a login when use the swaks commandline?
2. when I tyring to read the mail through a Java IMAP client, runs on the same debian server (imap server = localhost, port = 143), I am passing in the root username and password, the auth.log keep telling me the user is not found

When I install the Dovecot I choosed no ssl, and the postfix setting is internet site.

My guess is the SquirrelMail is using the linux login as Auth method
but somehow the mailserver's auth is disabled (no auth?)

How can I enable and create new username/password on my mail server, and I can use them to auth my IMAP and SMTP services?

Comment: Just to make it clearer for you, the authentication mechanism here is user authentication. ie. each mailbox is a real linux user. Debian does not have a password for root by default.

Comment: While not an answer, and it's completely personal preference, I prefer to setup using: https://workaround.org/ispmail . That guide allows you to create mail users that are not linux users, and makes managing them easier.

Comment: @WaleedHamra great guide, plus 1, but I am still keen to know the problem I am having at moment :(

Comment: swaks only tests sending mail to the server, you don't need a user/password from your local network for that. In other situations it can be necessary. roundcube also reads mail, so it needs user/password to access the mail.